# Disallow "Signing in with Google" to 3rd party sites

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business

Google has a feature they seem to call "Signing in with Google"

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/112802?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

In the Google Account settings it's listed as

[image]

You can see this in action if you have a Google account but don't have a TripAdvisor account. When you visit TripAdvisor.com a box will appear asking if you want to join/login with your Google Account.

[image]

[image]

How can I disable this feature? I never want that prompt to appear EVER. It's too easy to hit by accident, especially in a rush, and the moment you do the site gets access to a bunch of your info.

1. How can I disable this feature as a regular google user?
2. How can I disable this feature as a GSuites Admin so that none of my users can sign in to 3rd party sites with their google run corporate account?

Background: Yesterday I was trying to lookup a hotel from Band of Brothers the HBO TV series. Searching for Band of Brothers Hotel brought up the hotel. Clicking the first link took me to tripadvisor.com (on my phone). I don't know what I clicked. If that login prompt appeared it appeared for 0.001 seconds as I was in the middle of a conversation trying to **quickly** find where the hotel is, Switzerland or Austria and frantically clicking links to find its location. Today I get spam in my corporate email account from TripAdvisor with offers to book the hotel.

Of course now tripadvisor has my corporate email account in their database forever and I'm sure they've already shared it with 497 ad partners.

Comment: on superuser: [How to disable pop-ups for Google “YOLO” / “One-Tap Sign-Up”?](https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-pop-ups-for-google-yolo-one-tap-sign-up-in-chrome/1414942)

Answer (score 10):

Google YOLO login prompts can now be disabled in your Google Account settings:

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

> #### Google Account sign-in prompts
>
> Allow Google to offer a faster way to sign in with your Google Account on supported third-party sites

Uncheck that option to prevent the pop-up.

Also asked/answered on SuperUser here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-pop-ups-for-google-yolo-one-tap-sign-up

Comment: Thank you! Jesus this is again such a stupid Google move...

Comment: **Important: if you're signed into multiple accounts, the option needs to be disabled on all of them for the popup to completely go away.** Kinda really obvious but the lightbulb didn't go on until now... :)

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on iOS Chrome the prompt still appears as show in the bottom screenshot in the question

Answer (score -1):

Google Sign in cannot be disabled but you can disable many of the Google APIs. This will not grant access to any application that uses these specific APIs without the application to be white listed first.

Usually when you login to an application it required you to allow access to some resources, if is an application related to Gmail it will required access to read your emails or have some specific permission related to the service. If the application is related to Google Drive it will require permissions to manage or edit your files, you provide access to the application because you trust the application but with the sign in is something that cannot be disabled.

To disable access to the APIs you can go to *Security > API Permissions* and disable all the G Suite APIs so any user who wants to use an application may be signing to the app but will not be able to use it and the application will not have access to check any information related to the disabled APIs, just keep in mind that this will affect all the application you are currently using if you want to keep using them you will first have to trust the application by clicking on the "Trusted Apps" on the same page and check the trusted apps, then disable all the APIs so no one can use an application that is not white listed.

Here are some links for reference.

[Whitelist connected apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en)

[Enable API access in the Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en)