# How do I prevent websites from prompting me to sign in with Google?

Tags: google-account, firefox, authentication, website

How do I prevent websites from prompting me to sign in with my Google account: "Use your Google Account to sign in to X"?

[image: Sign In Prompt]

I've followed Google's instructions to ["Stop using Sign in with Google"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12849458?hl=en&sjid=12953706944676978907-NC#zippy=%2Csign-in-everywhere%2Chow-do-i-disable-the-sign-in-with-google-one-tap-prompt-and-automatic-sign-in), but the pop-ups continue to appear.

Is there an add-on for Firefox that can block such prompts? Perhaps a configuration setting for uBlock Origin?

Comment: Just followed the referred instructions. They worked for me using Chrome on a website that previously showed the Sign with Google prompt (loom.com). A question related to digg about why it works for Chrome but not for Firefox is off-topic here but might be on-topic in [su]. By the way, What is the operative system and what is version of Firefox that you are using?

Comment: Related from this site [Disallow "Signing in with Google" to 3rd party sites](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130401/88163), Related from [su]: [How to disable Google One Tap sign-up prompts?](https://superuser.com/q/1414410/152004)

Comment: Thanks, @Rubén. Do note that the answer on Super User doesn't work for Firefox 102.5.0esr (64-bit) on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a [GitHub post](https://github.com/yourduskquibbles/webannoyances/issues/228#issuecomment-678419176):

1. Click the puzzle piece icon (**Extensions**).
2. Click **uBlock Origin** (**Open extension**).
3. Click the gears icon (**Open the dashboard**).
4. Click the **My filters** tab.
5. Insert the following line:

   ```
   ||accounts.google.com/gsi/*$xhr,script,3p
   ```
6. Click **Apply changes**.

Enjoy a world without passive-aggressive sign-in prompts.

Note: You may need to install [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/), if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 3):

##### uBlock Origin (uBO)

uBlock Origin (uBO) is a customizable web browser add-on that helps to block ads, trackers, and malware sites.  [uBO Github Project](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)

One of the features of uBO is the ability to **remove** specific webpage **elements**.

**This ability is helpful for your use case since:**

1. An element containing the login prompt is overlaying (obstructing) the page content;
2. Manually dismissing the overlay element is an interruption to your browsing;
3. You don't intend to login, and logging in is unnecessary to view the content

##### Instructions

1. Download and install the FireFox [uBO extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)
   <sup>Links to other versions, see [uBO Installation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation)</sup>
2. Navigate to a URL that triggers the Google Sign-In element
3. Click on the uBO extension icon
   [image]
4. In the dialog box that opens, select the `Element Picker` (eyedropper).
   [image]
5. Hover over the element that you want to remove
   [image]
6. A dialog box will appear to allow code editing as well as other options including previewing and actually creating the filter
   [image]
7. You can select `PREVIEW` to test out the filter, `CREATE`  to apply it, and `QUIT` or <kbd>ESC</kbd> at any time will exit.
8. Clicking `CREATE` will create the filter and save it to your `custom list`.  The filter will only apply to the current website.

##### Accessing the `Custom List` of filters

1. Click on the uBO extension icon
   [image]
2. Click on the **Open Dashboard** icon
   [image]
3. Click on the `My Filters` tab
   [image]

#### Resources

- **Reddit Community:**
  [Posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/)    |    [Common Issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/wiki/solutions/)    |    [FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/wiki/index/)    |
- **Github**
  [Project](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/ublock-origin/)    |    [Documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#documentation)    |    [Wiki](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki)    |

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the AdGuard addon for Firefox.
2. In the addon's preferences, select Filters and enable "Annoyances".
   [image]
3. Click on the annoyances section, and you'll see many annoyances that you can enable or disable. Select any one of them that gets rid of the sign in prompt (for example, the "AdGuard Popups filter").