# Preventing a Facebook account from commenting

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Is there the possibility to set up a Facebook account so that the owner can still read people's content and use messenger, but without the ability to post comments?

My dad uses Facebook to keep in touch with his friends and relatives. He is getting older and is starting to sometimes post comments that are offensive or ludicrous.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is not a good fit for this site as it doesn't include enough details is unclear. The comment about your dad might be chitchat, if so, it should be removed, by the other hand if it's relevant you might have to reword the question.  You should have searched this site and the Facebook help center thoroughly before asking the question, then ask the question including a brief but complete description, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Once said the above, it might be interesting to know if you are interested in learning about how [se] works and if there are community members interested in cross-site collaboration. A question like this might be get feedback from community members from [softwarerecs.se], [interpersonal.se], and possible other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Umberto, it is not possible to disable the ability to comment on your father's Facebook account.  There are some parental controls and default privacy settings for teenagers aged 13 - 18, but they are intended more to protect the minor from the community, not the other way around.
<sup>[ [Facebook Parental Controls guide (Virgin Media)](https://www.virginmedia.com/blog/parental-controls/facebook) ]</sup>

If Facebook is being accessed through a web browser, you could install a browser extension such as uBlock Origin and use that to transparently remove the "commenting elements" from all Facebook pages.  See [my solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169274/) on this forum for removing "Google Login" prompts.  [That solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169274/)  could be adapted to remove Facebook commenting elements from the browser.